# Swift - AWS Authentication fetchSession - make global function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-amplify, swift5

I am using AWS authentication on my app. And I want to create a global function for fetching the user token so I can access it anywhere in the app whenever I need to fetch the new id token, the token is changing every 5 mins so I need to call it from time to time. I do it like this

```
    func fetchSession() {
        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { result in
            do {
                let session = try result.get()

                // Get cognito user pool token
                if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
                    let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()

                    return tokens.idToken
                }
            } catch {
                print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

but I am getting this error

```
Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

I also try to make it like this

```
func fetchSession() {
        let token = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { result -> AnyObject in
            do {
                let session = try result.get()

                // Get cognito user pool token
                if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
                    let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()

                    return tokens.idToken
                }
            } catch {
                print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the error I got

```
Cannot convert value of type '(AmplifyOperation<AuthFetchSessionRequest, AuthSession, AuthError>.OperationResult) -> AnyObject' (aka '(Result<AuthSession, AuthError>) -> AnyObject') to expected argument type '((AmplifyOperation<AuthFetchSessionRequest, AuthSession, AuthError>.OperationResult) -> Void)?' (aka 'Optional<(Result<AuthSession, AuthError>) -> ()>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify what `fetchSession` will return. Right now you are saying it will return `Void` because you have neglected the return type.

Here is an example of specifying the returned type.

```
func fetchSession() -> String? {
  // ...
  do {
    // ...
    return tokens.idToken // I assume idToken is a String
 } catch {
   print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
   return nil
 }
}
```

Do not forgot to return nil in the catch or rethrow the error.

Swift docs on functions: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: still getting the error `Cannot convert return expression of type 'AuthFetchSessionOperation' to return type 'String?'`

Comment: thats because `AuthFetchSessionOperation` is the type that actually is being returned. I simply used `String?` as a placeholder since I do not know what the actual type is.

Comment: If I used AuthFetchSessionOperation, it will give back this error again `Cannot convert value of type '(AmplifyOperation<AuthFetchSessionRequest, AuthSession, AuthError>.OperationResult) -> AuthFetchSessionOperation?' (aka '(Result<AuthSession, AuthError>) -> Optional<AuthFetchSessionOperation>') to expected argument type '((AmplifyOperation<AuthFetchSessionRequest, AuthSession, AuthError>.OperationResult) -> Void)?' (aka 'Optional<(Result<AuthSession, AuthError>) -> ()>')`

Comment: @SadDeveloper What this is telling you is that whatever type you are returning is not the type you said would return when you declared your function. My guess is if you explicitly return `'(AmplifyOperation<AuthFetchSessionRequest, AuthSession, AuthError>.OperationResult) -> AuthFetchSessionOperation?'` you might get somewhere.